# Redirect is not working in php, using header

Tags: php, redirect

I am wondering why this is not relocating me to the contact page?

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>


    <?php

    function setSessions($page){
        switch($page)
        {
            case "contact":
                $_SESSION['contact_name'] = $_GET['name'];
                $_SESSION['contact_address'] = $_GET['address'];
                $_SESSION['contact_phone'] = $_GET['phone'];
                header('Location:contact.php');
                exit;
                break;
            case "employment":
                break;
            case "position":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }




    $current_page = $_REQUEST['page'];
    setSessions($current_page);


    ?>
```

I am positive it is going in the contact case. 
thanks for the help

-edit: NVM, it works. Thanks!

Comment: NO output before a header, you should be getting an error

Comment: you are outputting a string, before the header that should be causing an error. You have error checking\display off which is a bad way to develop code

Comment: -post edit, still error checking must be off, so how would know if you got an error?

Comment: That white space is still output. just combine that all into one php enclosure

Comment: in addition you should use the full URI in header location not a relative one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send any output before making a call to `header()`.

You would have to remove:

```
<html>
```

and

```
echo "i got in here";
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

  `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.`

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

```
 <html>
```

You can't call header() if you have output anything to the browser. Move the redirect code above this html tag and remove that echo and you should be ok.

Comment: such a bad habit to get into though. just following the normal conventions would be a better approach to php

Answer (score 1):

For future reference white html space before header being called will also stop this from working. (lines 2 & 3)

Comment: 4 answers and 3 comments saying the same thing, but feel free to add your answer 20 minutes latter anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have ANY output what so ever before using header().  The echo statement in your switch statement is considered output and is the thing messing up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Any emission sends headers in PHP, and once you've sent headers you can't send any more.  Even whitespace will do this, but you have the string `<html>` being output.  You can't do that.

The better solution is to not do it and save all emission until after you have built everything that you want to output.

The worse solution would be to use output buffering.  At the start of your script but, `ob_start()`.  Then, headers will work as normal.

Comment: Okay, so i've taken out all the output, and now its just going to a blank page.

Comment: Are you sure it's not redirecting?  Or do the pages you're redirecting to just not have any content?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not getting the correct value for `$current_page`; you can echo that value and you will see it's empty. 
So what you need to do is you should take the current page value here
using this function:

```
function getMyurl(){

  $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  echo $url;

}

now $current_page=getMyurl();
```

You should know that getMyurl will return a full url of your website or application so you should modify it in your cases where it's written contact you should replace that with case "yourwebsite/contact".

It should now work for you